# Rewrite rule to hide extension .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to hide the extension of `.php` file from the link

for example `www.example.com/about.php`
To display  `www.example.com/about`

what I did

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and It works perfectly.

but I have another link which `example.com/news.php?id=45`
according to the above rule, I can access the link like

```
example.com/news?id=45 without .php
```

but I want to hide `id=45` I want it like this `example.com/news/45`

what I did  `RewriteRule ^news.php?id=([0-9]+) /news/$1 [NC,L]`

But It won't work I got 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: Hi @ADyson the error because of the code `RewriteRule ^news.php?id=([0-9]+) /news/$1 [NC,L]` when i remove it everything is ok , and there is nothing in error log

Comment: Which error log did you look in? Apache? PHP? Since htaccess is part of Apache, there should be information in the Apache log, if you've got logging configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this instead:

```
# MultiViews must be disabled for "/news/45" to work
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite "/news/45" to "news.php?id=45"
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)$ news.php?id=$1 [L]

# Handle extensionless ".php" URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,3}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Your 500 Internal Server Error was actually caused by your original directives that "hide" the `.php` extension, not your "new" directive (that wasn't actually doing anything). Your original directives would have rewritten a request for `/news/45` to `/news/45.php` to `/news/45.php.php` etc. creating a rewrite-loop (500 error).

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault with a detailed explanation of this behaviour: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

> what I did `RewriteRule ^news.php?id=([0-9]+) /news/$1 [NC,L]`
>
> But It won't work I got 500 Internal Server Error

The logic of this directive is reversed and would never actually match the requested URL (or *anything* for that matter), so won't actually do *anything*. It is, however, syntactically OK, so won't trigger an error.

The 500 error would have occurred simply by requesting `/news/45` (with your original directives), whether this directive was in place or not.

Comment: OK thank you now I can access the page `example.com/news/45` but the CSS is not working. @MrWhite

Comment: @MohammedJuma You are probably using relative URLs to your CSS files. You cannot use relative URLs if you are rewriting multiple URL-path depths, as you are doing here. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css) for more detail on this.

Comment: thanks, brother now it's working perfectly.

Comment: @MohammedJuma You're welcome. I've updated my answer with more explanation about the new directives and what was happening with your original directives and the 500 error.